# "Update lcd has encountered a p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m" on Eclipse after installing Hibernate plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

Well, as I said in title Eclipse launches that error after trying to create either Hibernate configuration File or Hibernate Console Configuration.

I must say I also have another installation of Eclipse working with ADT for android development, can that be the reasson of this mess?

Comment: Damn! Its more than a year and there's no answer to this.

Comment: i'm also having the same problem any idea how to fix this ??

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating a new project from quarkus get-started page and copying the .mvn and mvnw.cmd files from the new project to the project with the error and it started working.